# Django 1.9 get kwargs in class based view

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I was wondering if there is a way to get the kwargs directly in a class based view. I know this can be done in functions inside the class, but I'm having problems when I try this:

**views.py**

```
class EmployeesUpdateStudies(UpdateView):
    form_class = form_ES
    model = EmployeePersonal
    template_name = 'employeesControll/employees_studies_update_form.html'
    success_url = reverse('employee-details',  kwargs={'pk': kwargs.get('pk')})
```

My *url* is the following

```
url(r'^employees/detalles/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', login_required(views.EmployeeDetails.as_view()), name='employee-details')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `kwargs` in `success_url`, because when Django loads the class when the server starts, it doesn't have access to the request. Override the `get_success_url`  method instead.

```
def get_success_url(self) 
    return reverse('employee-details', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk']})
```

Comment: Great, you saved me. Thanx!

Answer (score 3):

Alasdair's answer solves your problem. You can however define a `get_absolute_url`  method for your `EmployeePersonal` model which will act as the `success_url` for your view:

> You don’t even need to provide a `success_url` for `CreateView` or
>   `UpdateView` - they will use `get_absolute_url()` on the model object
>   if available.

You'll use `self.id` in the `get_absolute_url` method for the model objects primary key.

---

Reference:

[Model Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#model-forms)

Comment: Your answer might help me in some other things in my application, thanx!